# The use of the word 'girl' in a movie/book title

Tags: grammar

There is a recent movie entitled *Gone Girl*. You may have seen it. I wonder why they used the noun *girl* instead of *woman* in the title, as the age of the *girl*, who is the subject of the movie, is about up to 30 years old? Is it because the title *Gone Girl* is more eye catching because using the same letter, *G*, on both words as marketing language rather than *Gone Woman*?

Comment: What is a "girl"?

Comment: Remember the _Golden Girls_?

Comment: I would humbly beg to differ slightly as it is about the _use of English language_, and the reasoning behind using certain words, in a book/film title.

Answer (score 6):

Interesting question.

Alteration, primarily. The two "G"s give the title a jaunty feel.

It is, in fact, based upon [a book, of the same name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_Girl_%28novel%29), by [Gillian Flynn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gillian_Flynn), who also wrote the screenplay. So it is not chosen by a Hollywood marketing team, but by the author herself. From [IMDB triva page on the film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2267998/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv):

> The first film screenplay written by Gillian Flynn and also marks as
>   the first film adaptation of any Flynn's works.

In addition, if I may be allowed to hypothesise, it is not uncommon to refer to a *woman* (especially up to the mid-thirties, but also beyond) as a *girl*, in a friendly [non-sexual/non-predatory/non-sexist] informal sense as it attempts to ignore the age of the woman. People, in general always like to [be made to] feel younger than they really are. In a similar way, a female may refer to a man as a "boy" to indicate his youthfulness, to compliment him, or merely to make him feel good [again in a non-sexist or demeaning way].

Also, it is a common idea, to never ask a woman her age, so again *girl* is more complimentary than *woman* or *lady*.

As an aside, as the film is about a woman who disappears and, generally, someone who has disappeared has a certain amount of sympathy attached to them. This can be emphasised by giving them a youthful quality. Similar to the word *kidnapped*. An old grandmother/grandfather can still be kidnapped.

Comment: Using "girl" or "girls" for alliterative purposes seems to be fairly common. Consider Golden Girls and Gilmore Girls.

Comment: Let's not forget the 80's classic _Gregory's Girl_... although we may wish to pretend that the unfortunate TV series _Gossip Girl_ had never existed...

Answer (score 3):

A girl means a female child, indeed, but there are other meanings for a girl according to oxford dictionaries: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/girl?searchDictCode=all . To mention a few a girl can mean 1)a young or a relatively young woman, 2)a young woman of a specified kind or having a specified job such as in a collocation "a career girl", 3)a person's girlfriend or daughter, 4)a woman who mix socially or belong to a particular group, team or profession or 5)a woman who is a female servant (outdated). Maybe some of these meanings could suit better to the movie title "Gone Girl". Furthermore, there can be other connotations to the word girl which can explain the word choice better but I'm not aware of them. I guess that the movie makers wanted to emphasize the particular characteristics or traits of the woman or her past possibly and that's why they chose a girl instead of a woman. "Gone Girl" also sounds more sensational and selling title than "Gone Woman" and it's more rhyming, catchy and memorable as you pointed out.